# an unwanted message is showing up in Chrome and IE on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, spam-prevention

there is an unwanted wanted message is showing-up in my wordpress site in chrome and IE.like:

```
<div class="blogtext2">
    <p>Unfortunately it provides a more difficulty than Which Is Better The Levitra Are The Cialis <a href="http://happylove.com.au" title="Which Is Better The Levitra Are The Cialis">Which Is Better The Levitra Are The Cialis</a> the established credit options available.Conventional banks by means of incomeif your age or financial cytotec generique <a href="http://buy2cytotec.com" title="cytotec generique">cytotec generique</a> company has never being foreclosed on track.Turn your online today this flexibility saves customers synthroid 50mcg <a href="http://buy4synthroid.com" title="synthroid 50mcg">synthroid 50mcg</a> that suits your entire loan.At that our approvals at conventional lending bupropion sr <a href="http://buy3wellbutrinsr.com" title="bupropion sr">bupropion sr</a> law we come around.Unlike a borrow money in which Plaintiffs Who Won Their Viagra Lawsuit In Court In 2010 <a href="http://buy1viagra.com" title="Plaintiffs Who Won Their Viagra Lawsuit In Court In 2010">Plaintiffs Who Won Their Viagra Lawsuit In Court In 2010</a> determine whether to them.Should you work together with get http://buy8tadacip.com <a href="http://buy8tadacip.com" title="http://buy8tadacip.com">http://buy8tadacip.com</a> yourself personal initial limits.Unsecured loans responsibly a paperless payday and buy clomid <a href="http://buy4clomid.com" title="buy clomid">buy clomid</a> proof that rarely exceed.With so it should find in buying the cheap inderal <a href="http://buy5inderal.com" title="cheap inderal">cheap inderal</a> loanin order to think cash quickly.Getting faxless hour loans who manage to spent it amoxicillin side effect <a href="http://buy9amoxil.com" title="amoxicillin side effect">amoxicillin side effect</a> after we are wary of unwelcome surprises.Ideal if so any unforeseen medical 500 mg ciprofloxacin <a href="http://buy6cipro.com" title="500 mg ciprofloxacin">500 mg ciprofloxacin</a> bankruptcy on for themselves.Third borrowers within days there unsecured loans feature online zovirax discount <a href="http://buy1zovirax.com" title="online zovirax discount">online zovirax discount</a> no upfront fees for your state.Seeking a loan even the reputation of personal protection against tadalis sx 20mg <a href="http://buy8tadalissx.com" title="tadalis sx 20mg">tadalis sx 20mg</a> possible identity or an easier for use.Open hours from finding a need them in Cialis Soft Tabs Half <a href="http://buy2cialis.com" title="Cialis Soft Tabs Half">Cialis Soft Tabs Half</a> via the assets available or days.Taking out for your set aside for online lenders and azithromycin 250 mg <a href="http://buy4zithromax.com" title="azithromycin 250 mg">azithromycin 250 mg</a> agrees to individuals are known as money.Do you show at financial able proscar drug <a href="http://buy8proscar.com" title="proscar drug">proscar drug</a> to what their loan.</p>
</div>
```

i m unable to find whats wrong with it.after checking my file i found that there was two meta tags in my header.php file as:

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="d-uffgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfNyoCOaEhWs" />
<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="sassasasdfdthghhyhyhyhyhybffg" />
```

after removing these lines the message is disappeared from chrome but still showing up in IE.please help me guys.

Comment: Are you using a pirated theme/plugin?

Comment: no man i m using twitter bootstrap theme. and all pluin are well verified.

Comment: Did you download all from `wordpress.org`? Have a look in your `functions.php` and check if all is okay. Try change your theme to see if the problem persists. If the problem is still here, you should check your plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first thing you could try is Clean cookies and then refresh the page.

It would be good if you give (personal message) the blog url :-)

Is there any fishy plugin installed? Try removing that as well.

If I think the other way, I think this is a spam comment which is appearing on your main page. Locate where this text is.

Does it appear on other pages such single blog post or page?

Comment: yes its appearing in evry page after <body> tag in <div class="blogtext2"> with <p> tag